# Задан @Qualifier, но все равно получаю NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type мой_интерфейс

Tags: java, spring

Есть интерфейс

```
public interface AddressInt {
}
```

Класс реализующий этот интерфейс

```
public class AddressA implements AddressInt {
    private String state;
    private String town;
    private String street;
}
```

Второй класс реализующий этот интерфейс (он такой же, но это не важно)

```
public class AddressB implements AddressInt {
    private String state;
    private String town;
    private String street;
}
```

Класс, который использует тип интерфейса

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String position;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("addressA")
    private AddressInt address;
}
```

Главный метод

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mySpringXMLConfig.xml");
    Employee empl = (Employee)context.getBean("employee");
    System.out.println(empl);
}
```

Сконфигурировано так

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    ">

    <!--Register AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <!--<context:annotation-config/>-->

    <bean id="employee" class="by.Employee">
        <property name="name" value="Nick Smith"/>
        <property name="position" value="Java developer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="addressA" class="by.AddressA">
        <property name="state" value="NY"/>
        <property name="town" value="New York city"/>
        <property name="street" value="5"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="addressB" class="by.AddressB">
        <property name="state" value="IL"/>
        <property name="town" value="Chicago"/>
        <property name="street" value="37"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Классика жанра и все просто, но при выполнении получаем

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [by.AddressInt] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [addressA, addressB]
```

Гуглил. У других людей вижу причины отказа, у себя не вижу. Квалификатор пробовал задавать разными способами (и в xml, и свою аннотацию писать), но итог один. В чем же секрет?

Comment: Занадка. Попробуйте `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier`.

Comment: @talex Прошу прощения, что не привел это в своем исходнике, но этот класс у меня импортирован в Employee

Comment: Должно работать. Попробуйте полную перекомпиляцию проекта. Может заело что-то :)

Comment: @talex Очистил и собрал заново (проект NetBeans с использованием Maven), запустил. Все равно. У меня java 1.8, а Spring 2.5.6. Может здесь собака зарыта, как думаете?

Comment: А аннотацию Service/Component вы куда дели?)

Comment: @GenCloud Я попробовал поставить Component во всех трех бинах. Результат тот же. Об этой аннотации я даже не думал. Ведь я указал в конфигурации все бины в элементах <bean>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` не поддерживает аннотацию `@Qualifier`. Чтобы она обрабатывалась, нужно вместо него использовать `<context:annotation-config/>`.

*Но есть один нюанс*.

`<context:annotation-config/>` работает на версии Java 5 и выше. Однако Spring 2.5.6 не знает о существовании Java выше версии 7, и всё что не 5, 6 или 7 он считает Java 4. Поэтому, если вы под Java 8 запустите проект с `<context:annotation-config/>` и Spring 2.5.6, вы получите изумительнейшую ошибку `Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher`.

Решить это можно целыми четырьмя способами. **Первый**, наиболее предпочтительный - обновить Spring. Актуальная версия - 5.1.3, но поддержка Java 8 появилась в 4.0.3. Если по каким-то причинам вам это не подходит, то **второй вариант** - добавить к одному из объявлений бинов `address*` свойство `primary="true"`. Тогда `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` будет использовать именно его везде, где есть больше одного кандидата этого типа. Если же вы хотите в одном месте использовать `addressA`, а в другом - `addressB`, а обновлять Spring вам не позволяют обстоятельства, то к вашим услугам **третий вариант** - отказаться от `@Autowired` и явно инжектировать бины в конфиге. Ну и **четвёртый вариант** - запускать вашу программу под Java 5-7. Крайне не рекомендую так делать, потому что JRE этих версий не поддерживаются, и могут содержать уязвимости и баги, которые никогда уже не исправят.

Comment: огромное спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!  Поменял версию Spring и теперь все работает :-)